Default strategy for discovering data fetchers in spring for graphql?
After reading the docs for Spring for GraphQL, I understand how to annotate methods and controllers to expose data fetchers for items in my schema. My question is.. do I need to do that for every field in my schema?
An example:
Say I have a type like this:
type Client { id: ID!, name: String!, user: User! }
Client is fetched from the database from another DataFetcher, and makes it to the ClientController. Id and Name are already fetched as part of the ClientDTO. Do I need to define a DataFetcher for those in the stock stuff provided from Spring?
For a little context: we are migrating from GraphQL Kickstarter which did recognition by Resolver or by the DataClass supplied as part of the resolver.

No, you don't have to register data fetchers for all existing fields, this would be really tedious. GraphQL Java automatically detects properties/getters and sets up PropertyDataFetcher for that.
When creating your GraphQL application, you can look at the schema inspection report during startup: this will point to the parts of your schema that are not yet covered by a data fetcher.

Thank you for the DataFetcher name of the getter/setter one. I did some digging and eventually found that.
